# View results of affine transform

Tags: opencv, affinetransform

I am trying to find out the reason why when I apply affine transformations on an image in OpenCV, the result of it is not visible in the preview window, but the entire window is black.How can I find workaround for this problem so that I can always view my transformed image (the result of the affine transform) in the window no matter the applied transformation?
Update: I think that this happens because all the transformations are calculated with respect to the origin of the coordinate system (top left corner of the image). While for rotation I can specify the center of the rotation, and I am able to view the result, when I perform scaling I am not able to control where the transformed image goes. Is it possible to somehow move the coordinate system to make the image fit in the window?

Update2: I have an image which contains only ROI at some position in it (the rest of the image is black), and I need to apply a set of affine transforms on it.  To make things simpler and to see the effect of each individual transform, I applied each transform one by one. What I noticed is that, whenever I move (translate) the image such that the center of the ROI is in the center of the coordinate system (top left corner of the view window), all the affine transforms perform correctly without moving. However, by translating the center of ROI at the center of the coordinate system, the upper and the left part of the ROI remain cut out of the current view window.
If I move ROI's central point to another point in the view window (for example the window center), an affine transform of type:
A=[a 0 0; 0 b 0] (A is 2x3 matrix, parameter of the warpAffine function)
moves the image (ROI), outside of the view window (which doesn't happen if the ROI's center is in the top-left corner). How can I modify the affine transform so the image doesn't move out of its place (behaves the same way as when the ROI center is in the center of the coordinate system)?

Comment: If you want to be able to apply any affine transform, you will not always be able to view it.  A better idea might be to manually apply your transform to 4 corners of a square and then look at the coordinates where those 4 points end up.  That will tell you where your image is going.

Comment: Ok, but what if I need to apply several affine transforms in a row? Affine transform of a black image is a black image. It's like that information is wasted. In my case, I need the transformed image for further processing. If I apply affine transform to a square, how will I be able to compute the new coordinates,in order to see where they are?

Comment: yes, you can always move your coordinate system somehow so the image fits in the window.  If you want a good answer, add specifics.  A good question might be.  "I have this shape (show image or specify coordinates), when I apply this scaling transform to it, it moves off the screen, I would like it to scale in place without moving, how do I modify this transform to accomplish that?"  Make it as specific as you possibly can.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I modified my question. Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to apply any affine transform, you will not always be able to view it. A better idea might be to manually apply your transform to 4 corners of a square and then look at the coordinates where those 4 points end up. That will tell you where your image is going.

If you have several transforms, just combine them into one transform.  If you have 3 transforms

```
[A],[B],[C]
```

transforming an image by A,then B, then C is equivalent to transforming the image once by

```
[C]*[B]*[A]
```

If your transforms are in 2x3 matrices, just convert them to 3x3 matrices by adding

```
[0,0,1]
```

as the new bottom row, then multiply the 3x3 matrices together, when you are finished the bottom row will be unchanged, then just drop it to get your new, combined affine transform

**Update**
If you want to apply a transform to an object as if the object were somewhere else.  You can combine 3 transforms.  First translate the object to the location you want it to be transformed in (center of coordinate system in your case) with an affine transform [A].  Then apply your scaling transform [B], then a translation back to where you started.  The translation back should be the inverse of [A].  That means your final transform would be

```
final_transform = [A].inv()*[B]*[A]
```

order of operations reads right to left when doing matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that I should apply all the transformations together, but what if the result of it is not viewable? Is the transformed image lost? If it's not lost then how can I use the image for further processing? For example how can I find a ROI of an image that I can't see?

Comment: If I apply affine transform to a square wouldn't its new position depend on the applied affine transform?

Comment: If the transformed image is lost then I assume you applied the wrong transform, why would you want to apply a transform to an image that moves the image completely off the screen?

Comment: If I apply the same transform (with corresponding elements in the matrices) and for one image the final result is visible and for other is not, then how can the affine transform be wrong? This is what I am trying to understand.

Comment: Now I am confused.  The same transform should have the exact same effect on two different images of the same size.  Please clarify the question.  Add images perhaps?  Or show the values of one of these transforms you are using.  State your goals clearly and show exactly what the problem is

Comment: This is what I am trying to do: I have an image set and for each image I need to apply affine transform consisting of a rotation around a point (the point is different for each image and it's implementation specific) followed by a scale. Then I apply the inverted transforms in the opposite order to test whether I will receive the same image with same orientation and scale as the original image. The problem is the scale that moves the image away from the screen.

Comment: Once it's away, other subsequent transforms are not applied. The same happens if you multiply all the transform matrices, the final image is not viewed on the screen.

Comment: Are you just trying to verify that matrix inversion works??  Just multiply your matrices together and if you get the identity matrix then you will "receive the same image with same orientation and scale as original image"

Comment: No, I'm not verifying matrix inversion. The problem is that after the affine transform, the resulting image is moved with respect to the center of the coordinate system which is in the top left corner, causing sometimes the image to be away from the screen. What if I like to perform affine transformation around some other coordinate system that has a different origin than (0,0) in the top left corner ( let's say it's in the center of the image)? Can I somehow move the origin of the coordinate system, so that the affine transform is performed with respect to the new origin?

Comment: yes you can.  Is this still the same question?  I am completely lost as to how what you are saying ties together.  Please update your actual question (not just add new comments) to reflect your specific problem and the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Can I translate the object to any other location which is not the center of the coordinate system and still obtain the same results of the combined affine transform?

Comment: Wherever you transform the object with [A], it will scale as if it were scaled in that location with [B].  Changing the translation will change the results.  I think you need to play around with a few examples and get a feel for how this works.

Comment: Ok, I have to say it finally works. I was using a wrong function for matrix multiplication (multiply instead of *), that's why I was receiving strange results. So, the problem was elsewhere not in the affine transforms=>Being a programmer beginner sucks! Thanks a lot for all your explanations!